# Scrolling Right Div Unknown Width

Tags: html, css

I want to have a scrolling div to the right but I don't know what the width of that box needs to be.

If I set it to auto, it stops at maximum width 100%, when I give 100% that doesn't help either. I want the inside div to go as long as it needs to create the scrollbar at the bottom. The only way I found it to be working is to give it actual width but I cannot interpret what the width of the inside div will be...

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/n0kzm82d/

In this example I entered width for each insider element in theory even though I know what each box's width will be, I don't know how many divs will be there.

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 250px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div style="width: 3000px;height: 250px;">
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
              1
              </div>
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
              2
              </div>
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
              3
              </div>
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
              4
              </div>
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
              5
              </div>
              <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
              6
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try this (using JS for calculating all child divs width) ...  https://jsfiddle.net/n0kzm82d/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you can use `white-space: nowrap` on parent element and use `display: inline-block` on child elements

```css
.wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrap > div {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: initial;
  color: white;
}

.wrap > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work either. It works in the snippet. I am displaying multiple Google Charts in this div and I wanted that to scroll. Maybe something about jQuery made it so it was not able to scroll. I simply added a code to calculate how many divs will be there and multiply that with 300px (each of them has this much width) and printer as width of the inside box. That works for now. That's the only way I can come up.

Comment: I cannot show a live example but thank you very much for your time. Since yours did actually work in snippet I chose yours for now.

Answer (score 1):

- Simply replace the `width` to `min-width`.
- As for specificity, declaring a style attribute inside a tag overwrites the style written in your *yourStyle*.css file, so in most cases it is not the best practice to declare the style inside the HTML element, but it is surely acceptable (just added a small note).

  ```
  <div style="width: 100%;height: 250px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div style="min-width: 3000px;height: 250px;">
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
        1
        </div>
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
        2
        </div>
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
        3
        </div>
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
        4
        </div>
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:red;">
        5
        </div>
        <div style="min-width:300px;height:250px;float:left;background:blue;">
        6
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: min-width does not help

Comment: Nope that won't help either. I have no idea why. But it's okay. Thank you for your help :)